# SQLite-Net Extensions unable to create tables with OneToOne relationship

Tags: sqlite-net-extensions

I created two classes, Item and Warranty. Item holds a reference to Warranty, and Warranty is tagged with a foreign key attribute. I'm following the same pattern as on the wiki page, yet I keep getting "doesn't know about Warranty" error.
Here's what my classes look like:

Item class

[image]

Warranty class

[image]

This is what I call to create the tables and the very first line is throwing the error.
[image]

Comment: I don't get it, why are people downvoting instead of trying to help? My code attempt is exactly like one of the snippets from the developer. https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

Comment: I didn't down voted, but maybe posting screenshots of the code instead of the code itself is irritating to some readers.

Answer (score 0):

`OneToOne` attribute inherits from `Ignore` sqlite.net attribute. If your sqlite.net is trying to create the `Warranty` column is because you have two sqlite.net libraries in your project.

Depending on what SQLite-Net Extensions versions you used, you may have included a different sqlite.net library. Remove your old sqlite-net dependency or use the SQLite-Net Extensions suitable to your current sqlite-net library.